# Establishing concurrence of digital sensor data for reporting

Tags: powerbi, sensors, dax

**Summary:**

Establish when multiple sensors are active, but the sensor only reports when state is changed. Tools to use are almost exclusively DAX or PowerQuery, unless it makes more sense to do some sort of web app for pre-processing the data.

**Longer:**

I have sensor data that comes to me in the form of timestamped 1's and 0's. These sensors live inside conference rooms and measure three different aspects of activity in the rooms, which all live in the same table. It seems that we have all the pieces there, I just don't know how to parse this to see what all is active at any given time.

Of particular interest to the client is how many of these sensors are active at once. However, I am at my wit's end to try and figure out how to establish concurrency of data when all I have to go off of is sensor state change (from 1 to 0 or vice-versa). Time is recorded in Unix time.

To make matters more difficult, the data arrives via a data gateway in Power BI. The data source refuses to enable DirectQuery, so I cannot modify a SQL statement. Sample data is below:

## SensorTable

```
ID | DigitalValue |     Time      |    SensorType    |
1         1          1519966800           1
1         0          1519967000           1
1         1          1519970000           1
1         0          1519980000           1
1         1          1519996800           2
1         0          1520067000           2
1         1          1520070000           2
1         0          1520080000           2
```

This is one of my first projects in the realms of data analytics and I just think I don't know enough to ask the almighty google the correct questions to get an answer. Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: @HelpfullHound - it'd be helpfull if you provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: Your sample data shows an ID field, but two different sensor types. Is your ID not unique? Or does the combination of ID and sensor type produce a unique key? How many sensors are there altogether? A handful? A dozen? Hundreds? This could affect options for how to analyse and present the information.

Comment: This appears similar to a question I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974856/how-to-calculate-inventory-per-day-from-movement-table-with-power-bi-dax/51975588#51975588) before. Your problem is slightly simpler, but maybe this will help point you in the right direction.