# Get open tickets by month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to work out how to add a measure to calculate defects that have been approved but not implemented, by month

My data table has the following columns:

`Created Date` - always has date

`Closed Date` - has date if closed or null if not closed

`Date Approved` - has date if approved of null

I have a separate date table linked to `Created date`,

```
Created = COUNTROWS(fcr)
```

with a `userelationship` for closed

```
Closed Date = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table),
                  USERELATIONSHIP(Dates[FullDateKey], table[Closed Date]), 
                  NOT(ISBLANK(table[Closed Date])))
```

`userelationship` for date approved

```
Date Approved = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table),
                    USERELATIONSHIP(Dates[FullDateKey], table[Date Approved]),
                    NOT(ISBLANK(table[Date Approved])))
```

Results so far:
[image: image of the results so far]

The last piece is driving me mad.  I'm trying to create a measure to show defect resolutions approved but not closed by date (month, year, week etc).

Comment: This sound similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974856/how-to-calculate-inventory-per-day-from-movement-table-with-power-bi-dax). See if you can use any of the logic from there.

Comment: was useful, managed to extract logic and solved my issue