# Count orders (users, devices or employees) by current status

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-manipulation, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem that has been daunting me for weeks.  I have found very similar problems and associated solutions, but none have really given me the necessary insight to achieve my objective, so I am reaching out to SO.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974856/how-to-calculate-inventory-per-day-from-movement-table-with-power-bi-dax) comes close to capturing the problem, but I need a variation on this problem.

Using the original OP's table, I have a table of orders (Inventory):

| ID | TimeStamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/08/2018 | A |
| 1 | 21/08/2018 | B |
| 1 | 24/08/2018 | C |
| 2 | 19/08/2018 | A |
| 2 | 20/08/2018 | B |
| 2 | 22/08/2018 | C |
| 2 | 24/08/2018 | D |
| 3 | 18/08/2018 | A |
| 3 | 21/08/2018 | B |
| 4 | 15/08/2018 | A |
| 4 | 17/08/2018 | B |
| 4 | 24/08/2018 | D |

I need to show the number of items in each Status on each day.  The output would be like this:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/08/2018 | 1 | - | - | - |
| 16/08/2018 | 1 | - | - | - |
| 17/08/2018 | - | 1 | - | - |
| 18/08/2018 | 1 | 1 | - | - |
| 19/08/2018 | 2 | 1 | - | - |
| 20/08/2018 | 2 | 2 | - | - |
| 21/08/2018 | - | 4 | - | - |
| 22/08/2018 | - | 3 | 1 | - |
| 23/08/2018 | - | 3 | 1 | - |
| 24/08/2018 | - | 1 | 1 | 2 |

The solution offered by [Alexis Olsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765226/alexis-olson) was only for counting the items in Status B.

```
CountB = 
VAR CurrDay = MAX(Inventory[TimeStamp])
VAR Summary = SUMMARIZE(
                  FILTER(
                      ALL(Inventory),
                      Inventory[TimeStamp] <= CurrDay
                  ),
                  Inventory[ID],
                  "LastTimeStamp",
                  MAX(Inventory[TimeStamp])
              )
VAR LookupStatus = ADDCOLUMNS(
                       Summary,
                       "Status",
                       LOOKUPVALUE(Inventory[Status],
                           Inventory[ID], Inventory[ID],
                           Inventory[TimeStamp], [LastTimeStamp]
                       )
                   )
RETURN SUMX(LookupStatus, IF([Status] = "B", 1, 0))
```

However, I need a measure that can count items for any possible Status.  Of course, I can create separate measures for each possible Status, but that would never work.

In my case, I am not trying to track items through inventory status: I am trying to track users by day by Application Version number.  So where we see Status A, B, C and D, I would have versions 2.1.1, 2.1.2, ... 2.3.0 ad infinitum and continually adding new version numbers.  I need to know how many users are at the latest release and how many are still using older versions.  Each time a user uses the app, the log records which version they have.  So my real-world table would be called Log and it would have User_ID, Date, App_Version instead of ID, TimeStamp and Status.

I can create a fixed list of version numbers, but obviously, I cannot create a measure for each one.  Any ideas?

---

Addendum for use of Power Query instead.

I have written a PQ script that transforms the data into a table that looks like this:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/08/2018 |  |  |  | A |
| 16/08/2018 |  |  |  | A |
| 17/08/2018 |  |  |  | B |
| 18/08/2018 |  |  | A | B |
| 19/08/2018 |  | A | A | B |
| 20/08/2018 | A | B | A | B |
| 21/08/2018 | B | B | B | B |
| 22/08/2018 | B | C | B | B |
| 23/08/2018 | B | C | B | B |
| 24/08/2018 | C | D | B | D |

Now. obviously, this could be problematic with 10k users over 3 years, so I was wondering if DAX would not offer something else *(and save me from looking like a complete clown when it is pointed out to me)*.

Comment: duplicate it, but change value to A, same for other status? Or am i thinking too simple now?

Comment: thanks, but no, that is actually the point. I certainly could make a measure per status, but that does not scale very well and would hellish as the number of software release versions climbs into the dozens per year.  It is possible to completely throw away the solution from Alexis and use something different. I have tried several such approaches and they all fail. The approach from Alexis illustrates a working solution to a simplified formation of the problem.

Comment: Ah, now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

try to pivot the status column in power query

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried ETL solutions, but the scale of the data is quite large. thousands of users over hundreds of days. The table reaches a combinatorial explosion pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically create this in Power Query if you needed it as a base table. You definitely would not do this in DAX. However, if you only need to analyse as per your expected results then the following works fine.

Table:

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Measure = COUNTROWS('Table')
```

Add the fields to a matrix as follows:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @DavideBacci. Thank you for this. I have wondered if that was the case - that putting this into DAX would create the same combinatorial explosion as ETL.  I will add a notation about doing this in PQ. And I will give your approach a go.

Comment: Not really - but I am getting close now.  I have been using a method from [Radacad](https://radacad.com/power-bi-hr-pattern-dax-measures-for-the-last-position-to-date-last-status-to-date) that allows me to calculate state of each user without having to boil the ocean in PQ. It has some useful byproducts as well, such as the from-to transition table that facilitates sankey as well as other measures that can serve as KPIs (e.g. average time to upgrade after new release).